# When I submit form, I am getting Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to POST a form to my `testexe.php` using an Ajax request, however, whenever I add the data type gateway in my Ajax request I get the Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded error message. Is there something I am doing wrong here? I am able to get the `button value` successfully but not sure why `gateway` is giving me problems.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .box1 {
        width: 450px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        margin: 0;
        display: flex;
    }

    .col {
        display: inline-block;
        border-right: 2px solid black;
        padding: 5px;
        width: 200px;
    }

    .col:last-child {
        border-right: none;
    }

    input[type=text], select {
            width: 20%;
            padding: 12px 20px;
            margin: 8px 0;
            display: inline-block;
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
                border-radius: 4px;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                background-color: #ffffff;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="gatewayInput">
<form method="post">
      <input type="text" id="gateway" name="gateway" placeholder="Gateway Name"><br><br>
      <?php 
        include("search.php"); 
      ?>    
</div>
<div class="box1">  
<label class="col">Up/Down</label>
<span class="col">
  <input type="radio" name="option" id="r1" value="1" />
  <label for="r1">Up</label>
  <input type="radio" name="option" id="r2" value="2" />
  <label for="r2">Down</label> 
</span>
 <span class="col">
  <input type="submit" class="button" name="submit"/>
 </span>
  </form>
</div>
<script src ="../../../jqueryDir/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src ="../../../jqueryDir/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  //auto seatch function
  $(function() {
      $( "#gateway" ).autocomplete({
          source: 'search.php'
      });
  });

  //button click function
    $(".button").click(function(event){
        if ((document.getElementsByName("gateway")[0].value == '')) {
               alert('Gateway Required!');
        return false;
    }
        else if (document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]:checked').length < 1) {
               alert('Please Choose Value!');
               return false;
        } 
        else {
               //alert('Sucess!');
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
            url:"testexe.php",
            type: "POST",
                    data: {
              gateway: gateway,   //when I add this it give me the error
              option: $('input[type=radio]:checked').val() 
            },
            dataType: "text", 
            success:function(result){
                        $('#div1').html(result)
            }
            });
             return true;
        }
  });

</script>
<div id="div1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

testexe.php

```
<?php
//when the submit button is clicked
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
  echo "yay I got the POST!";
  if(isset($_POST['gateway']){
    $gateway = $_POST['gateway'];
    echo $gateway;
  }
}

(removed code for simplicity)
?>
```

search.php

```
<?php
//database configuration
$dbHost = 'localhost';
$dbUsername = 'user';
$dbPassword = '';
$dbName = 'database';

//connect with the database
$db = new mysqli($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);


if(isset($_GET['term'])){
    //get search term
    $searchTerm = $_GET['term'];

    //get matched data from skills table
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE tablename LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY tablename ASC");

    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = $row['tablename'];
    }

    //return json data
    echo json_encode($data);
    mysqli_close($db);
}
?>
```

error message:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at Function.type (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
at Ab (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
at Ab (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
at Ab (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
at Ab (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
at Ab (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
at Ab (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
at Ab (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
at Ab (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
at Ab (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
```

Comment: You don't appear to define the JavaScript variable `gateway` used in your `.ajax()`. You need to actually grab the element from your form and assign it to this variable.

Comment: @ObsidianAge you mean like this `gateway: $("#gateway"),` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```
$.ajax({
  url:"testexe.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: {
    gateway: $("#gateway").val(),
    option: $('input[type=radio]:checked').val() 
  },
  dataType: "text", 
  success: function(result){
    $('#div1').html(result)
  }
});
```

Mistakes was `gateway: gateway`.
I assume you want to pass the `gateway` value from the `input textbox`.

Changed code `gateway: $("#gateway").val(),`

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
gateway: $("#gateway").val(),
```

you have to take value of gateway with this method like you did for option

```
gateway: gateway,   //when I add this it give me the error
option: $('input[type=radio]:checked').val()
```